# Unity setting up custom HID item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hid

EDIT: So I was trying to have my Grayhill Touch Encoder work on Unity on a Linux.

When I run `sudo cat /dev/usb/hiddev0 | hexdump -C` I am able view raw data from the for the custom HID.

However, there was no generic USB Port to allow serial to read from the USB. I believe this is the correct terminology. What matters was there was nothing in built Unity to allow me to have my custom HID talk to Unity.

So after talking to the direct company themselves, they needed to make custom drivers for the Grayhill touch encoder.

Another solution to the problem was to create a generate mouse descriptor to have the Grayhill Touch Encoder act like a mouse, but this needed a custom firmware update requested to the company.

Comment: Are you using the correct device?  See bottom of you link.  Different devices you need to send different commands.

Comment: Are you talking about the screenshot of the input actions? I have the device selected with the checkbox. Which specific part are you talking about in the link? I even paired the device with the PID / VID.

Comment: The link "Device Matching".

Comment: yeah, if you look at the very bottom of my code, you can see me doing that. `    matches: new InputDeviceMatcher()
        .WithInterface("HID")
        .WithCapability("idVendor", 0x1658) // VID
        .WithCapability("idProduct ", 0x0060)); // PID  `

Comment: I tried two different methods for this part, VID / PID and Manufacturer / Product. Both don't seem to get me anywhere. I figure VID / PID would be best because the addresses are very specific.

Comment: Run some test code and enumerate through all the options and output. Then once you get the list you can hard code the right one in your code.